# Map keybind to specific snippet - SQL Management Studio / Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, ssms

I review a lot of code and I want to put brackets around certain text elements that lacks them. So far I've been been doing the following:

1) Highlighting the text element I want to put brackets around (only one highlight at a time)

2) Hit ctrl-k + ctrl-s to invoke the "Surrond With..." shortcut (see Edit->IntelliSense->Surround With...

3) Find my "insert bracket" code snippet and then hitting enter

I want to keybind **a specific snippet** to do this in one go (just like when you are commenting out a block using the keybind ctrl-k + ctrl-c. Is this possible?

This question is smiliar to [Assign code snippet to keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312507/visual-studio-11-code-snippet-key-shortcut-to-specific-snippet) but its not marked as answered. Can anyone help confirm that its not possible or whether another work-around is possible.